# inapp purchase billing: QueryInventoryFinishedListener failed to find purchased item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am testing my app with a managed item that I purchased.

Then I wanted to try to purchase the product with the same id again (with purchase flow). I therefore have cleared all play store data. After that I was able to purchase the product again.

Now I am wondering that if a user cleans the play store data accidentally (or looses his/her purchase for any other reason), will he/she then loose his/her purchase?

I didn't expect that behavior, because I thought that the purchase information is stored on google's remote servers.

Code example:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (mHelper == null)
                return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error here
                return;
            } else {
                if (inventory.hasPurchase(PremiumUtils.SKU_AD_FREE)){
                    // User paid to remove the Ads - so hide 'em
                    hideAd();
                }
                else{
                    // Free user - annoy him with ads ;)
                    showAd();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: I edited the text for better readability.

Comment: I am interested here, after clearing data, it should hide the ads unless you consumed the purchased earlier. Whats is your observation, please share.